# Pandas: Find time patterns

Tags: python, pandas, performance, time

I have a dataframe with two columns. One column is an ID and one column is a timestamp in microseconds precision.

[image]

I want to identify every id, which occurs more than n times in a given period. Let's say I want to identify every id that occurs atleast 100x in 5 minutes.
My code works, but is slow and seems rather complicated and not pandaish:

```
def getInfoDict(ip, start, end, num):
    return {
    'ip': ip,
    'start': start,
    'end': end,
    'num': num    
}

dtypes = {'ip.src': 'str','frame.time_epoch': 'str'}
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, usecols=[0,9], names=['ip.src','frame.time_epoch'], dtype=dtypes)
df['frame.time_epoch'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['frame.time_epoch'],unit='s')

result = []
timeout = pd.Timedelta(value=300,unit='s')
for ip in df['ip.src'].unique():
    subset = df[df['ip.src'] == ip]
    if len(subset) > 49:
        start = 0
        counter = 0
        for index, row in subset.iterrows():
            if start == 0 or pd.Timedelta(row['frame.time_epoch'] - start).microseconds > 300000000:
                start = row['frame.time_epoch']
                counter = 1
                continue
            counter = counter + 1
            end = row['frame.time_epoch']
        if counter > 99:
            result.append(getInfoDict(ip, start, end, counter))
                
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

What is a better way to do this? I have been looking into pandas series, but i could not figure out how to do this.

Comment: you can create a 5min group on frame.time_epoch by `df['tag'] = df['frame.time_epoch'].astype(float)//300`, then `df.groupby(['tag', 'ip.src']).size()` to find every 5min range, which ip is appears more than given times.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done in 4 lines.

```py
groups = df.groupby(['id'])
for name, group in groups:
    if (group['time'].diff(periods=499) < 300000).any():
        print(name)
```

**Explanation**:

Let's say your dataframe `df` contains 2 columns: `id` and `time`. First, group the dataframe by `id`. Check [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for pandas groupby.

Since we have grouped by `id`, each group will have one `id` and all the `time` values in which `id` occurs.

We loop through groups and do a `diff` with `periods=499` on the time column. This means we do `500th timestamp - 1st timestamp`, `501st timestamp - 2nd timestamp` and so on. (The first 500 values will be NaN). Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) link for pandas diff method.

We check if any of this difference is less than 5 minutes (`< 300000`). If that's true there have been at least 500 different occurrences in less than 5 minutes.

Finally, we print the name (that is, `id`) if the check is true.